# Query parameters dropdown menu from table in fast api

Tags: fastapi, fastapiusers

I would like to retrieve drop-down menu in query parameters from sql query is there a way to do it I have checked over the internet and find nothing

I have checked over the internet and find nothing only I found enum passing and it is not helping in my case